# Duplicate Preludes in Mask of Nyarlathotep differ from original

Tags: eldritch-horror

The rulebook for [Masks of Nyarlathotep - Prelude Cards - Page 4](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/43/47/4347db33-4b2d-45a7-bdee-7eb0b6230e4d/eh09_rulebook.pdf) states

> Four Preludes in this expansion (Beginning of the End, The
> Dunwich Horror, Twin Blasphemies of the Black Goat, and
> Call of Cthulhu) originally appeared in previous expansions
> (Mountains of Madness, Strange Remnants, The Dreamlands,
> and Under the Pyramids respectively). If playing with those
> expansions, do not include the duplicate Preludes in the
> Prelude deck.

However the **Twin Blasphemies of the Black Goat** Prelude have been corrected according to the Errata. So it's not a duplicate it's a correction and really they should have included this twice.

And **The Dunwich Horror** Prelude had the word *Glamour* removed. This change was not listed in the Errata. So again not a duplicate.

> After resolving setup, each investigator gains 1 <del>Glamour</del> Spell. Then, if Yog-Sothoth is not the Ancient One, spawn the Dunwich Horror Epic Monster on Arkham.

What's going on?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question here but generally, when referring to duplicates Eldritch Horror means the card title specifically, not necessarily the entirety of the card's contents.

Comment: It's a duplicate in title only, that explains it. Thanks. I'm guessing **Glamour** was removed because MoN doesn't have Glamour spells. Curious that they choose to put a SR logo on the card as this will make it really difficult to put it back in the MoN box post game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when Eldritch Horror refers to duplicate cards, it explicitly refers to the title of the card, not the entirety of the card's contents. Additionally, if a board game replaces a card because of a typo or explanation update, it's recommended to remove the original card entirely for the updated card.